# What is status of this patent

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [USD114437](https://www.google.com/patents/USD114437)

Answer (score 2):

Thats more than 70 years old and has therefore expired. It does not get any protection anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As per 35 U.S.C. 173 Term of design patent. Patents issued from design applications filed on or after May 13, 2015 shall be granted for the term of fifteen years from the date of grant. Patents issued from design applications filed before May 13, 2015 shall be granted for the term of fourteen years from the date of grant.

so its expired.